# Preferred/minimum height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Does anyone know how to make a DIV behave in such a way that it will always try to consume it's maximum space (Regardless of content)?

For example, if I have a DIV with a `max-height` of `600px` and a `min-height` of `200px`, how can I make it so that:

- If the window height is greater than `600px` enough it will occupy `600px`
- If the window height is between `600px` and `200px` it will occupy all available height
- If the window is `200px` or less it will always occupy `200px`?

An alternative to the above that I could live with would be to ignore the minimum height and just let it scale all the way down.

Eventually, I would like to vertically align it within the window but first things first.

I'd prefer to use pure CSS for this if possible. If it comes to it, I won't have too much trouble writing a script to achieve it.

Any suggestions welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only the `height` property you may obtain this behaviour using a set of mediaqueries

```
div {
   height: 200px;
}

/* needed to stretch the height of div */
@media all and (min-height: 201px) and (max-height: 600px) {
   html, body {
      height: 100%;
   }
}

@media all and (min-height: 201px) {
   div {
      height: 100%;
   }
}

@media all and (min-height: 601px) {
   div {
      height: 600px;

      /* if you need to vertical-align the div, use following rules */
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
   }       
}
```

---

Live Example (basic): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPGbNq
Live Example (with vertical alignment > 600px) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyYVag

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I've managed to extend this to vertically align it too. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. For reference, I took the same approach with vertical centering, however I used `margin-top: -300px` instead of `translateY(-50%);`. Yours is more flexible, but mine suffices for my needs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a very simple way without media queries by combining `height`, `max-height` and `min-height`. The browser mediates between them.

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/gav12da5/)

**EDIT - VERTICAL CENTRING**

To include vertical centring, there's also a smart way without media queries or CSS transforms. This solution should therefore work in IE8.

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/gav12da5/1/)
Vertical alignment using [this smart technique](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was what I attempted first but I didn't set HTML and BODY to 100% height. Seems to work quite well. Any idea how to extend this solution to vertically align within the window?

Comment: since it's an important detail, could you specify this in the question itself? is this required even when the window height is < 200px ?

Comment: It is in the question, though just as a desirable extra. Just thought I'd ask the question. By extending your answer @FabrizioCalderan I've managed to vertically align it though. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for delay, had to take a call. See edit for a IE8 friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

see this .it will take 100% width and 100% height at any width and height of windows.

```
 div{
display: block;
background: red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7f7tn3d/)